# Remove part of a string from a variable jquery

Tags: jquery, string, replace, variables

I'm trying to take the id of a mouseover and strip out part of the ID, to leave me with just the core text I need to act on.

My mouseover will return an id such as "nevadaActiveArea", but I need to manipulate that string down to just "nevada". All the searches I've run speak to how to do this on the contents of some element, but I just need the text in a variable. How do I achieve this?

Final code based on Josh Stodola's answer:

```
$("area").mouseover(function(){
    var overID = $(this).attr("id");
    if(overID.indexOf("ActiveArea") >= 1){
        id = overID.substring(0, overID.indexOf("ActiveArea"));
    }else if(overID.indexOf("Hotspot") >= 1){
        id = overID.substring(0, overID.indexOf("Hotspot"));
    }

    $("#"+id).show();
});
```

Comment: do you have any control over the ID name? You'll want to make sure it's consistent in some form. It's also nice to have some sort of delimiter character to trim against such as nevada-activeArea

Comment: I could add a delimiter if it would simplify things. I actually have two possible strings to remove. Some are nevadaActiveArea and some are nevadaHotspot. I could easily enough convert the ids to nevada-ActiveArea and nevada-Hotspot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that all IDs end in "ActiveArea", you can do this using substring and indexOf...

```
$("#nevadaActiveArea").mouseover(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  id = id.substring(0, id.indexOf("ActiveArea"));
  alert(id);
});
```

Comment: Should have mentioned this- I actually have two possible strings to remove. Some are nevadaActiveArea and some are nevadaHotspot. I tried running your on one and it worked perfectly, but when I run it back to back it broke it.

Comment: Used this to figure out the rest, edited my question with the answer